# How can I override configuration in .p4config?

Tags: environment-variables, perforce

P4EDITOR is set to "vim" in .p4config and I want to use a a different editor inside my Python script. If I change the environment variable P4EDITOR="custom_editor", it has no effect. Seems like perforce looks for .p4config file first and then loooks for environment variables.
OS : freeBSD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th best approach would be to upgrade the p4 version and do `p4 -E P4EDITOR="custom editor"` as suggested by @Bryan.

If upgrading P4 is not an option then copy the the existing .p4config file to a temp file and add `P4EDITOR=custom editor` to the temporary config file. If the `P4EDITOR` is already set, then modify it in the temporary config file. Also do `export P4CONFIG=temp_config` to make the temporary file as the config file.

p4 looks for the config file in the current directory and all it's parents. So the best way to find which config file should be copied and modified is by executing the command `p4 set P4CONFIG`. This is very useful if there are multiple config files on the machine.

```
$ p4 set P4CONFIG 
P4CONFIG=.p4config (config '/<path>/.p4config')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a new-enough version of the command-line, use `p4 -E P4EDITOR="custom editor" command...`; The '-E' flag is described in `p4 help undoc`, and is specifically intended for overriding variables like P4EDITOR in this way.

Alternately, try setting the environment variable P4CONFIG to something other than ".p4config". Then you won't be using your .p4config settings at all, and your custom setting for P4EDITOR will be in effect. Unfortunately, then you'll have to ensure that you preserve all the other settings from your .p4config file that you wish to retain.

Comment: thank you! The P4 version is pretty old. Updating is not feasible since the script would be run on a number of machines. I was thinking of the second approach, copying the existing .p4config and editing only P4EDITOR. But what effect would P4ENVIRON have?

Answer (score 0):

Use P4CONFIG="" to tell Perforce to not look into P4CONFIG files at all.